# Batch : getting the last folder name from a absolute path

Tags: path, batch-file, directory, absolute

I am using a Batch script to automatically backup files to my NAS and I need to get the last folder name from an absolute path, like from "C:\Things\Folder" to "Folder"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can use:

```
Set NasPath=C:\Things\Folder
Set NasFolder=%NasPath%
:GetFolder
Set GetFolderTemp=%NasFolder:*\=%
If Not %GetFolderTemp%==%NasFolder% (
    Set NasFolder=%GetFolderTemp%
    Goto :GetFolder
)
Echo NasPath  =%NasPath%
Echo NasFolder=%NasFolder%
Exit /B
```

Whatever you do, don't put quotes around any part of the `Set NasPath=...` statement.  Use quotes this way:

```
Set FromPath=C:\Program Files\Blah
Set NasPath=C:\Things\Folder
RoboCopy "%FromPath%" "%NasPath%"
```

Do not use quotes this way:

```
Set FromPath="C:\Program Files\Blah"
Set NasPath="C:\Things\Folder"
RoboCopy %FromPath% %NasPath%
```

Comment: +1, But you should always use quotes this way `Set "FromPath=C:\Program Files\Blah"` else you fail with `Set FromPath=C:\Documents & Settings`

Comment: @jeb `SET FromPath=C:\Docs and Settings` is valid. Like @Hand-E said, to use the variable, enclose it in quotes, `"%FromPath%"`.

Comment: It's obvious that `Docs and Settings` works, but with an ampersand it fails, and ampersands are allowed in file/pathnames

Answer (score 2):

To not have any issue with space, I propose this code:

```
Set NasPath=C:\Things\My Space\Folder
Set GetFolderTemp=%NasPath%
:GetFolder
FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=\" %%1 IN ("%GetFolderTemp%") do (
set NasFolder=%%1
set GetFolderTemp=%%2
)
if not "a%GetFolderTemp%"=="a" goto :GetFolder

echo %NasFolder%
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `C:\Program Files\Mickey\Mouse`-like paths (without quotes), you could also use the following code:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set path=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Mickey\Mouse
:shift
for /f "tokens=1* delims=\/" %%i in ( "!path!" ) do (
    set folder=%%i
    set path=%%j
)
if not [!path!] == [] goto :shift

echo folder: !folder!

endlocal
```

Comment: Please be aware that this will overwrite the `PATH` environment variable.